# Android OpenGL ES 2 Random Model Deformation

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, assimp

I've ported a desktop OpenGL application to Android NDK (under OpenGL ES 2), and there seems to be a random deformation of my mesh. On most application runs, it looks 100% perfect, but sometimes it looks as follows:

[image]

The inconsistency of the problem is the most concerning to me. I don't know if it's because of my Android simulator, or if it's something else.  Through my testing, I can establish that it's either:

- An OpenGL setting that doesn't play nice on Android, but does on everything else
- A bug in the Open Asset Import Library (Assimp) which I've compiled by hand to work on Android
- A bug in the Android simulator

My model process looks as follows:

On every draw:

```
- bind the program
- change the uniforms

- if (has vao support)
    - bind vao

- enable all vertex attribute arrays

- for every mesh
    - bind array buffer
    - set the attribute pointer for each vertex array
    - bind element buffer
    - bind texture & set uniform of texture location
    - glDrawElements

- disable all vertex attribute arrays
```

And this is the actual code:

```
glUseProgram(program_);

if (loaded_vao_)
{
    #if !defined(TARGET_OS_IPHONE) && !defined(__ANDROID__)
    glBindVertexArray(vao_);
    #else
    glBindVertexArrayOES(vao_);
    #endif
}

glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition_);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vTexCoord_);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(boneids_);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(weights_);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vbo_.size(); i++)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_[i]);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition_, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vTexCoord_, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<void*>(texcoord_locations_[i]));

    #if !defined(TARGET_OS_IPHONE) && !defined(__ANDROID__)
    glVertexAttribIPointer(boneids_, 4, GL_INT, 0, reinterpret_cast<void*>(bone_id_locations_[i]));
    #else // APPLE OR ANDROID
    glVertexAttribPointer(boneids_, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<void*>(bone_id_locations_[i]));
    #endif

    glVertexAttribPointer(weights_, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<void*>(bone_weight_locations_[i]));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo_[i]);

    // Textures
    if (!textures_.empty())
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_[texture_numbers_[i]]);
        glUniform1i(textureSample_, 0);
    }

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ind_size_[i], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

glDisableVertexAttribArray(vPosition_);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(vTexCoord_);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(boneids_);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(weights_);
```

As well, my vertex shader looks as follows:

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;
attribute vec4 boneids;
attribute vec4 weights;

uniform mat4 pos;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 scale;
uniform mat4 rotate;
uniform mat4 proj;
uniform mat4 bones[50];
uniform int has_bones;

varying vec4 color;
varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0f);
    texcoord = vTexCoord;

    vec4 newPos = vec4(vPosition,1.0);

    if (has_bones == 1)
    {
        mat4 bone_transform = bones[int(boneids[0])]*weights[0];
        bone_transform += bones[int(boneids[1])]*weights[1];
        bone_transform += bones[int(boneids[2])]*weights[2];
        bone_transform += bones[int(boneids[3])]*weights[3];

        newPos = bone_transform * newPos;
    }

    gl_Position = proj * view * pos * scale * rotate * newPos;
}
```

Do note that I've tried commenting out the `bone_transform` in the vertex shader, and the problem still persists.

EDIT:

It seems that I was able to recreate some deformations on my Linux OpenGL 3.3 version by removing any assimp optimization post process flags:

```
scene = importer.ReadFile(file_path.c_str(), aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_LimitBoneWeights | aiProcess_ValidateDataStructure);
```

Based on the output of the Assimp::DefaultLogger, there's no errors or vertex warnings.

Comment: Is the error consistent when it happens, or totally random? If it's not it's most probably the initialisation issue. Does it happen with all meshes?
Unrelated to your question, why are you using a VAO at all? The point of VAO is not having to setup the buffers and vertex attributes every time you draw.

Comment: Without the VAO, I was having some rendering issues on newer Android phones.  It might be just hiding a bigger problem though.  
It's totally random.  Small sections of the model expand out (sometimes it's the face, hat, etc), but it always seems to be a small amount and not the entire thing exploding.  
The issue seems to only be with this model.  The only real difference for this model is that it's defined by 3 "meshes" (the for loop runs 3x), and it has a lot more vertices than the rest.  
I haven't seen a model with only 1 "mesh" have this bug.

Comment: Are the models that you get from the library exactly the same every run? If they are and you are getting different results, that would remove that as a source of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be a part of Blender's COLLADA export, or Assimp's COLLADA reader.

By exporting to FBX and using Autodesk's free FBX to DAE tool, the deformation was fixed.

- Blender was version 2.71
- Assimp was version 3.1.1

Assimp, even with all logging and data integrity flags on, did not post any errors about corruption, so I don't know which component to blame.  Regardless, I'm happy I've found a workaround.